# Program crashes and does not display correct output

Tags: c++, crash, numbers

So I am working on a very "basic" problem for my c++ class and have encountered some errors. The problem is this

> An interesting problem in number theory is sometimes called the “necklace problem.” This problem begins with two single-digit numbers. The next number is obtained by adding the first two numbers together and saving only the ones-digit. This process is repeated until the “necklace” closes by returning to the original two numbers. For example, if the starting numbers are 1 and 8, twelve steps are required to close the “necklace”:
>   18976392134718
>   Write a program that asks the user for two starting numbers, and then displays the sequence and the number of steps taken. The program output should look similar to:
>   Enter first number: 1
>   Enter ssecond number: 8
>   18976392134718
>   Your numbers required 12 steps.

What I have done is this:

```
` #include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int necklace(){

    int firstNumber, secondNumber, total = 0, counter = 10, sumOfTwo, tempOne, tempTwo, count;



    // 2 single digit numbers
    // add first two numbers and save only one digit
    // process keeps going until original numbers are found

    cout << "Enter the first number: \n";
    cin >> firstNumber;
    cout << "Enter the second number: \n";
    cin >> secondNumber;

    sumOfTwo = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    while (sumOfTwo >= 10){
        sumOfTwo /= 10;
    }
    int numbersArray[] = {firstNumber, secondNumber, sumOfTwo};

    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){


        tempOne = numbersArray[i + 1];
        tempTwo = numbersArray[i + 2];



        sumOfTwo = tempOne + tempTwo;
        while (sumOfTwo >= 10){
            sumOfTwo %= 10;
        }

        numbersArray[i + 3] = sumOfTwo;


        total++;

        if(tempOne == firstNumber && tempTwo == secondNumber){
            break;
        }


    }


    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbersArray); i++){
        cout << numbersArray[i];
    }

    cout << endl << "It took " << total << " steps to finish. \n";

    return total;
}


int main() {

    necklace();


}


`
```

The problem I am getting is that it will print out all the numbers except the original 2, for example if I use the example with 1 and 8, it will print out 189763921347 and then crash, when it is supposed to print out 18976392134718 with the 1 and 8 at the end of it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What do you see happening when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: You have UB with your arrays 19+3 is out of range of 3 element array

Comment: @KenWhite so i'm using xcode and when I put it through there and compile it, the program runs and once it reaches the step where it prints out the numbers (189763921347) it gives me Thread 1: Sigabrt or when I run through terminal I get the error Abort Trap: 6

Comment: @JakeFreeman Do you mind explaining that? Not really understanding what you're saying

Comment: I didn't ask you what compiler you were using. I asked what you see **stepping through the code in the debugger**, which allows you to execute it line by line and inspect variables.

Comment: @DavidK you have an array named numbersArray which has a size of 3. You attempt to access elements which are not supposed to be their

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)`, followed by ... `tempTwo = numbersArray[i + 2];`. Given that `i` can be as high as 20, this could potentially execute `numbersArray[22]`. Which doesn't exist, since you clearly, and straightforward-ly declared this array as containing only three elements. And not 23. Accessing the 23rd element of a three-element array is undefined behavior. The fact that your code managed to run through the end before blowing up is commendable, but doesn't change the fact that this is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @KenWhite I mean I'm not that experienced with programming but what I came up with was that If i comment out the line numbersArray[i + 3] = sumOfTwo; it will run incorrectly, but it will stop giving me the error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok that makes sense! Thanks so much!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok so I changed my code by not giving numbersArray a definite value, and instead adding the three values seperately, but now the code does not run properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: The only thought that I have is that neither myself, nor anyone else, has any idea what your code currently looks like, it would be logically impossible to figure out what is the reason it doesn't work now, without actually reviewing the actual code. Could be some other logical error that was introduced while you made your changes. Or, could be a logical error in the existing code. After spotting the original, obvious, failure, there was no reason to spend any more time analyzing the rest of the code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numbersArray[] = {firstNumber, secondNumber, sumOfTwo};
```

with three elements on the right hand side makes it an array of size 3. Meaning with indexes 0, 1 and 2.
The use of higher indexes will result in Undefined Behaviour (UB).

On the other hand:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){

    tempOne = numbersArray[i + 1];
    tempTwo = numbersArray[i + 2];
    [...]
    numbersArray[i + 3] = sumOfTwo;
```

with `i` up to 20 (included) indexes this very same array from 0 to 23 for the last line!

Next:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbersArray); i++){
```

`sizeof(numbersArray)` returns the size **in bytes** of the array:

```
sizeof(numbersArray) = 3 * sizeof(int)
```

Higher than 3, the real size of the array.

---

But, if you intend to print the values but not store them, you don't need an array. You just need to "exchange" the values like:

```
one two   // beginning of loop
  ___|
 |    __ new_digit
 |   |
 v   v
one two   // end of loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions as to what I can do to correct it?